# Disable update tips from wp-admin page in WordPress site

Tags: wordpress

How can I disable update tips from wp-admin page? My WordPress wp-admin page showing this warning:

> An automated WordPress update has failed to complete - please attempt the update again now.

But "Update" section of "Dashboard" shows that my WordPress, theme and plugins are up to date. How can I remove this warning? Also help me to completely disable this type of tips from my wp-admin page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is generated from a file called `.maintenance` in the root of your WordPress installation. To remove the message you simply need to delete the file.

source: http://www.wpmods.com/forums/topic/an-automated-wordpress-update-has-failed-to-complete

**Edit:** To remove all udpate tips from now on, paste the following code in your `functions.php` file:

`if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_users' ) ) {
  add_action( 'init', create_function( '$a', "remove_action( 'init', 'wp_version_check' );" ), 2 );
  add_filter( 'pre_option_update_core', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );
}`

This code will remove all update notifications for all the wordpress users with rights to edit other users (usually administrators)

Comment: But how to completely disable this type of messages?

Comment: I'm sorry, I had forgotten about that. I've updated the answer to include the solution to this issue too.

Comment: Code is taken from: http://www.wpcookies.com/remove-wordpress-update-notice-from-admin-panel/ . But this is not working for me.

Comment: Mmm.. I can't test it myself because my two wordpress installations are already updated, but it seems that there are some plugins for that: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-wordpress-core-update/ and http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-wordpress-updates/ would be two examples.

Answer (score 0):

This filter is sufficient for Wordpress 3.0:

```
add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_core', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );
```

For 2.8 to 3.0 use this:

```
remove_action( 'wp_version_check', 'wp_version_check' );
remove_action( 'admin_init', '_maybe_update_core' );
add_filter( 'pre_transient_update_core', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );
```